# Stove spark igniter make the touch switch off/on

Tags: circuit-analysis, noise, flipflop, emc

I've made a capacitive touch/on (currently on bread board) with [TTP223](https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove-Touch_Sensor/res/TTP223.pdf) touch IC on active low mode and used 74HC74D as output flip flop. When I use this board near stove and power up the stove spark igniter some times (20% of times) the output of the switch changes.

What is the reason?

- What should I do to avoid this kind of false operations?
- Is it possible that the bread board connections or the wires I used act as an antenna and absorb the noise?

This is the schematic I used on flip flop section:
[image]

Thank you in advance
Eric

Answer (score 2):

CMOS are very sensitive to "external" "pulses".
You should, first, use a decoupling capacitor, nearest possible to Vcc and ground of 74HC74.

Comment: thank you, Antonio for your reply, is  a 100nF capacitor enough  for the decoupling purpose?

Comment: It is a classical value. Enough for some "spikes". For **each** IC ... If not, try a higher value as 1uF.  A breadboard is not really the best thing near a "spark igniter".

Answer (score 2):

*What is the reason?*

EMI.

*What should I do to avoid this kind of false operations?*

Proper PCB layout with strong decoupling, possibly with termination resistors on inputs.

*Is it possible that the bread board connections or the wires I used act as an antenna and absorb the noise?*

Yes.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply